`ModuleNotFoundError` when running Python script with a custom module despite correct `sys.path` setup and conda environment
Problem
I'm working on a Python project with the following structure:
apx-cv/
├── utils/
│   └── custom_object_functions.py
│   └── utils.py
├── models/
│   └── sample_configurations.py
└── test/
    └── run_files_ee-opt.py

The utils directory contains various utility functions, and I'm trying to import them into the run_files_ee-opt.py script located in the test directory. Here's the relevant part of the run_files_ee-opt.py script:
from utils.custom_object_functions import create_hollow_room, get_arrow, create_coordinate_axes_mesh

# Rest of the code...

I'm running this script within a conda environment named apxcv. The sys.path includes the empty string '', which I understand should represent the current working directory.
However, when I try to run the script from the project root (apx-cv) using the command:
python test/run_files_ee-opt.py

I encounter the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'

I also want to mention that earlier I have been running this script from PyCharm, and it works smoothly there. Now, I want to run it on a remote machine using terminal. When I run it using terminal, it does not work on the remote machine, or even my local machine.
The problem persists with all modules not just utils, because I wasn't able to import models either. I think I am missing something very basic, but I am not a very strong computer programmer, so I don't know much.
Things that I have tried:

Verified sys.path: I printed sys.path inside the script, and it correctly includes the current working directory ('').
Absolute Import: I ensured that I'm using absolute imports (not relative imports), so from utils.custom_object_functions import ... should be valid.
Checked Working Directory: I confirmed that the working directory is the project root (apx-cv) when running the script.
Also checked utils.utils is not making an issue, as I excluded all utils-related methods. Even then, I still cannot import models.

The script should run without the ModuleNotFoundError since the utils module is in the correct location, and sys.path appears to be set up correctly.


The sys.path includes the empty string '', which I understand should represent the current working directory.

This is only true when you run python on a file that is in the local directory, like this:
python myscript.py

But you are running python with a script file in a different directory:
python test/run_files_ee-opt.py

So in this case, sys.path does not include the empty string, it includes the string 'test'.
